# Probability of UKVI issuing me a visa

Tags: student-visa, uk-visa

I studied in the UK on a tier 4 visa September 2019 but, due to course difficulty and unsuitability, I had to withdraw from the course on January 2020 and my visa was curtailed.

I am now planning to continue my studies in the UK at the same university on different subject which I am keen and interested to study and have been offered on the programme.

Please can I get advise whether there is a probability of UKVI issuing me a visa or refusing it.

Comment: Did you overstay at all on your original visa? What evidence do you have of the suitability of the new course?

Comment: This is impossible to answer. Even if every single facet of a new visa application is exactly the same as the prior one (which seems unlikely), a new application will in any event be reviewed by a different ECO, who may weigh matters differently and reach a different conclusion. The only way to know for sure if you can obtain a UK visa is to apply.